# Compare rights of two users on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

For me, one user is working fine. Other user got some problem with the permission.

I would like to compare two user accounts on SQL Server.

Is it doable with queries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to get the user permissions with a system stored procedure [sp_helplogins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190304.aspx):

```
EXEC sp_helplogins 'User'
```

or use a [SQL Compare tool](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/).